# use karate dsl for api automation testing with data drven approach (want to avoid multiple scenario if the steps are same)

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

How to use karate dsl for API Automation testing where I am calling an api (test data) whose response is passed as request body for web api. There are multiple cases with different sets of data hence wanted to know if there is way to have only one scenario which can perform same steps for different data sets.

web api request structure (schema) is complex one like below

{
"date": 1624406400,
"AID": "IND",
"BID": "Z1",
"UserID": "User1",
"BD": [
{
"fromid": "01:00",
"toid": "02:00",
"pd": [
{
"P": 1,
"Q": 10,
},
{
"P": 2,
"Q": 11,
},
]
},
{
"fromid": "01:00",
"toid": "02:00",
"pd": [
{
"P": 1,
"Q": 10,
},
{
"P": 2,
"Q": 11,
}
]
}
]
}

Comment: if the linked answer does not answer your question, please assume that what you want is not supported by karate